# How to make a macro universal and usable everywhere

Tags: excel, vba

I have written several macros that I would like to have accessible with a keyboard shortcut any time I open ANY workbook, not just in one specific workbook. Is there a standard procedure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making an add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up finding another solution to this as well. If you only want your macro available to you whenever you open an Excel worksheet (as opposed to distributing it to others), choose to save your macro in Personal Macro Workbook.